# Domain name best practice when the last letter of the first word and first letter of the second word are the same

Tags: usability, urls

If I'm registering a two word domain in which the last letter of the first word, and the first letter of the second word are the same, is it better to drop usage of one of those letters?

Examples:

- Nigel Lighting - `nigellighting.com` or `nigelighting.com`?
- NYC Cheese - `nyccheese.com` or `nycheese.com`?

Comment: I've wondered this too and always came to the conclusion that making a special rule for this one case isn't a good idea.  I wonder if anyone has evidence to the contrary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Use the fully typed words

Don't drop the first letter off the second word just because it happens to match.  Dropping the first letter of the second word **implies a new one word trademark**.

- ### DirecTV

**People usually type out the full words** of things they are searching for as evidenced by this image which was captured from the DirecTV homepage...

[image: directv]

As a window washer I would rather use one of the following URLs instead of trying to educate the entire world to only type one W...

- ### windowwasher.com
- ### window-washer.com

Perhaps if you are a guy named **Asher** who cleans **Window**s and all the locals know you as "Window Asher" then dropping the second `W` makes sense...

> - [windowasher.com](http://www.yell.com/biz/asher-s-window-cleaning-london-7197697/)

## ☻

Comment: I frequently wound up on the wrong page trying to go to https://www.paygoonline.com/ when the real url is https://www.paygonline.com/. My brain and fingers type the full words and it takes training/editing to omit letters.

Answer (score 5):

Like DaveAlger said, **use the fully typed words**.

I would however also consider getting both domains, and redirect one to the other, but using the fully typed one as the main. This makes it even easier for users and could prevent abuse.

Comment: +1 good suggestion.  http://directtv.com redirects to their trademarked name